# Mostrar datos de Mysql en una tabla PHP

Tags: php

Tengo que mostrar datos de usuarios en una tabla en php pero aparace el error  Undefined variable $cnnPDO in * direccion de documento php*
adjunto imagenes de codigo y ejecución
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aclaro que registro, login y deslogeo asi como el registro de alta funcionan correctamente
agradeceria la ayuda gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que 
algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el 
[Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio 
y en [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: La variable **$cnnPDO** es la que utilizas para conectarte a la base de datos, asegurate de incluir tu archivo de conexión, por ejemplo: include('conexion.php);